# Python mysql syntax error, throwing error on correct? syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to check if a record with a specific id already exists. It worked before, but now I keep receiving an error which is telling me my syntax is wrong.

The syntax:

```
            cursor.execute(
            "SELECT username, COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE hwid = %s GROUP BY username",
            (hwid)
        )
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\dev\colpabot\main.py", line 42, in on_message
cursor.execute(
File "C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 577, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 695, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 582, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s GROUP BY username' at line 1
```

Table strucute:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text. And in this case you have missing comma between `username` and `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Note, in the image there was NO comma between `username` and `COUNT(*)` and also  `(hwid)` is not tuple. it has to be `(hwid,)`

Answer (score 1):

You forget a comma.

"SELECT username, COUNT(*)..."